# App Engine continues to serve previous Python version

Tags: python, google-app-engine, deployment

It seems recently (within the year) that when I deploy an update to an *App Engine* app it continues serving the previous Python code.

I can go to the console and under:

*Versions -> Debug -> Source*

see that the most recent version has been deployed. And when it errors out, the link given in the log points to the new source, but based on unambiguous results, it is the old source that is in fact serving. This has been happening on multiple apps and the only solution has been to wait a day and try again.

The command I am using to deploy from the local Windows development environment is:

```
gcloud app deploy --project xxxxxxxxxx --version 1
```

I have tried bumping the version number but the results are the same.

What could I be missing?

Further attempts: I changed the deploy command to:

```
gcloud app deploy --project xxxxxxxx --promote --stop-previous-version
```

I removed the version switch so that App Engine would create its own version numbering. The results are the same: the previous version continues to serve.

Just to verify, I added a logging line:

```
logging.info('Last edit: 5/28/2018 11:08')
client_id = os.environ['CLIENT_ID']
logging.info('CLIENT_ID = ' + str(client_id))
```

The first line was added, the other two are old. In the log trace, it shows output from the second log, not the first. What is truly strange is that the line number in the log indicates the middle line, so it is displaying the new source, but executing the old.

Comment: Further investigation:

Answer (score 3):

I am using the original App Engine SDK for Python. Evidently, you have to run locally in order to generate the .pyc file. It was working locally, but running into problems on the web. So I made some tweaks to fix the problem, but did not try to run locally afterwards. So although the uploaded .py was new, the .pyc was old.

Comment: To avoid such problem you may want to check your `skip_files` section in your `app.yaml` config file, you may be overwriting the `- ^(.*/)?.*\.py[co]$` default pattern which should prevent uploading of the local `.pyc` files to GAE and thus force their re-generation on GAE for every deployment. See the default `skip_files` config at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#runtime_and_app_elements